# For matrix $A$, $~~~~A\times A^2=A^3$ OR $A^2\times A=A^3$

Tags: matrices

Find the cube of a matrix $$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&&2&&3\\4&&5&&6\\7&&8&&9\end{matrix}\right]$$ I found the $A^2$ but I am confused what to do next to find the cube.

May I do $$A\times A^2=A^3$$ or I should do $$A^2\times A=A^3$$

Comment: Either will work. You don't have to worry about commutativity here since it is covered by associativity. That is, $(A\times A) \times A= A \times (A\times A)$ which implies $A^2 \times A = A \times A^2$.

Comment: More generally, powers of an element in any ring always commute: $a^na^m=a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$. This is true regardless of whether the ring is a commutative ring or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is associative: for any three matrices of appropriate dimension,

$$ (A \cdot B) \cdot C = A \cdot (B \cdot  C) $$

This extends to products of any number of terms, not just of three terms.

In particular, setting $A=B=C$,

$$ A^2 \cdot A = A \cdot A^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is associative but not commutative

in your case $A^2\cdot A = A \cdot A^2$ and you get this by using the property of associativity $A^2\cdot A =(A\cdot A)\cdot A =A\cdot (A\cdot A) =  A \cdot A^2$